# Apache SSL Remotestorage Server Not Working

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2, remotestorage

I am trying to set up my Ubuntu web server to host a [remotestorage](http://remotestorage.io) server utilising the [php-remote-storage](https://github.com/fkooman/php-remote-storage/blob/master/SERVER.md) server.

I have not setup SSL on my server before, so a fresh-ish apache2 install is present. I've followed the instructions to the letter, jusr replacing all occurances of `storage.local` with my own subdomain, lets call it `sub.example.com` .

`sub.example.com` is directed to my web server from AWS Route 53. This works for `other.example.com`

So when I browse to `sub.example.com` it just times out. Chrome says:

```
This site can’t be reached

sub.example.com unexpectedly closed the connection.

Try:

Reloading the pageChecking the connection

ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

I dont know how to find out what's wrong. All other hosted sites work so I'm guessing im doing something wrong with the SSL bit.

Thank you.

Jon

Edit: my default-ssl.conf (just as it comes, I haven't modified it) :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        #   Server Certificate Chain:
        #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
        #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
        #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
        #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
        #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
        #   certificate for convinience.
        #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

        #   Certificate Authority (CA):
        #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
        #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
        #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
        #                to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #                Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
        #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

        #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
        #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
        #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
        #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
        #                to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #                Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
        #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

        #   Client Authentication (Type):
        #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
        #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
        #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
        #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
        #SSLVerifyClient require
        #SSLVerifyDepth  10

        #   SSL Engine Options:
        #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
        #   o FakeBasicAuth:
        #        Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
        #        the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
        #        user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
        #        Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
        #        file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
        #   o ExportCertData:
        #        This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
        #        SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
        #        server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
        #        authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
        #        into CGI scripts.
        #   o StdEnvVars:
        #        This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
        #        Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
        #        because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
        #        useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
        #        exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
        #   o OptRenegotiate:
        #        This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
        #        directives are used in per-directory context.
        #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
        #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
        #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
        #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
        #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
        #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
        #        This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
        #        SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
        #        the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
        #        this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
        #        mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
        #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
        #        This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
        #        SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
        #        alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
        #        practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
        #        this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
        #        works correctly.
        #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
        #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
        #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
        #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
        #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
        #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>  
</IfModule>
```

And the remotestorage, php-remote-storage ssl conf (see link above):

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName storage.local

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/storage.local_error_log
TransferLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/storage.local_access_log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/storage.local_combined_log combined
LogLevel warn

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName storage.local

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/storage.local_ssl_error_log
TransferLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/storage.local_ssl_access_log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/storage.local_ssl_combined_log combined
LogLevel warn

DocumentRoot /var/www/php-remote-storage/web

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/storage.local.crt
#SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/storage.local-chain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/storage.local.key

SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off

# HSTS (mod_headers is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"

<Directory "/var/www/php-remote-storage/web">
    Options -MultiViews

    Require all granted
    #Require local

    AllowOverride none

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>

# Limit the request body to 8M
LimitRequestBody 8388608

XSendFile on
XSendFilePath /var/www/php-remote-storage/data/storage

# Pass through the "Authorization" header
SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: provide your ssl config file code

Answer (score 1):

I had some troubles getting it up as well. Some of my problems were due to:

You have to replace 'ServerName storage.local' by your actual hostname. That certificate will fail for any other hostname.

Also, if you haven't generate the SSL encryption keys, the apache2 server will fail to load once it tries to load the certificates specified by your config file. Specifically:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/storage.local.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/storage.local.key
```

Also, you want to disable (a2dissite) the different websites that specify a  DocumentRoot different from /var/www/php-remote-storage/web

After observing these steps, I got it running.

Now I wanted to know how to host 2 webservices at the same time, with different DocumentRoot folder, through the same port (443), with with some different alias (like: server.com/nextcloud and server.com/privatestorage).